# How can I have substantially more users than views?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to understand the reason I have 100x more Users than Views in GA4>Reports>Pages and Screens (6 Views vs 1200 users for the same time period).  I looked at Page_View and Screen_View events in https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069 but I'm still missing something in my understanding.